# Настроить api Express.js для работы с SPA

Tags: express, spa

Имеется простенькое api на Express.js с несколькими эндпоинтами. Необходмо на каждый гет запрос отправлять index.html для корректной работы SPA. Выглядит примерно так:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
// });

app.use('/dictionary', dictionaryRouter);
app.use('/user', userRouter);
```

Проблема в том, что в таком виде блокируются все остальные гет-запросы у эндпоинтов и вместо json от них приходит html файл. Есть ли возможность получать index.html на каждый запрос + json-респонс?

Answer (score 0):

Немного намудрил, но похоже уже разобрался)
Эндпоинты на фронте и бэке имели одинаковый урл, в чём и была проблема. Немножно правок, и всё работает:

```
app.use('/api/dictionary', dictionaryRouter);
app.use('/api/user', userRouter);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

/dictionary возвращает index.html, а vue-компонент стучится уже к /api/dictionary, что корректно возвращает json.